# iOS error Expected ')'

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables, c-preprocessor

First I define a value.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define SLIDE_TOP 100;
#define SLIDE_BOTTOM -100;

if(distance > SLIDE_TOP){
    NSLog(@"TOP");
}
```

I found same errors

1.
ViewController.m:98:19: Expected ')'
2.
ViewController.m:98:19: If statement has empty body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `#define` something, the preprocessor simply substitutes replacement tokens (everything after the identifier) for the identifier in the source code. So, your if statement looks like this after the preprocessor runs:

```
if (distance > 100;) {
    NSLog(@"TOP");
}
```

Note that the semicolon after "100" *is* included. The compiler doesn't expect the statement to end there, because there's an unmatched open parenthesis, so it complains that you're missing a ')'. The fix is to remove the semicolon from the end of the `#define` statement:

```
#define SLIDE_TOP 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these

```
#define SLIDE_TOP 100;
#define SLIDE_BOTTOM -100;
```

to

```
#define SLIDE_TOP 100
#define SLIDE_BOTTOM -100
```

`;` is not required in `define`.

Comment: The suggestion is correct, but the last sentence is misleading. You can put whatever in a `#define` and it will be blindly substituted by the preprocessor. In this case a `;` doesn't make sense, but in other cases it might.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.